# Java Dimension for JFrame. setSize(new Dimension(x,y));

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt

I have a question. When I'm setting the size of a JFrame and I add a new dimension. Is that number millimeter or pixels? I want to set the size to 3in by 3in. So I'm using (300, 300) but it seems a little big.  How do I set the size in inches?

Cool this is how I solved it in case someone wants to know:

```
// Get a Toolkit instance.
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();

// Get resolution in pixels per inch.
int pixels_per_inch = tk.getScreenResolution ();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is in pixels.

Using [information from the `Toolkit`,](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenResolution%28%29) you can convert inches to pixels.

If you are going to use Java 2D (which is recommended for the best quality), you can also use [a normalizing transform.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getNormalizingTransform%28%29)

Comment: nice find on that Toolkit method (also nice family name =)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that all AWT/Swing dimensions are pixels, unless otherwise stated.  The conversion of pixels per inch is device independent, meaning each display (or printer, etc.) will have it's own pixel density.